# 2 same queries database return different results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I'm using Yii2 ActiveRecord & ActiveQuery to retrieve data from database, but I'm facing different results:

```
    $ne_lat = 53.42712825923;
    $sw_lat = 53.39008549731;
    $ne_lon = -2.1651649475098;
    $sw_lon = -2.288761138916;

    $poi = Point::find()

        ->andWhere('latitude <= :ne_lat', [':ne_lat' => $ne_lat])
        ->andWhere('latitude >= :sw_lat', [':sw_lat' => $sw_lat])
        ->andWhere('longitude <= :ne_lon', [':ne_lon' => $ne_lon])
        ->andWhere('longitude >= :sw_lon', [':sw_lon' => $sw_lon])
        ->andWhere(['status' => 1])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

returns 0 an empty array. But same query get just by a little bit different way:

```
   $poi = Point::findBySql('SELECT * 
      FROM `point` 
      WHERE (((((latitude <= 53.42712825923) 
      AND (latitude >= 53.39008549731)) 
      AND (longitude <= -2.1651649475098)) 
      AND (longitude >= -2.288761138916)) 
      AND (`status`=1))
   ')->asArray()->all();
```

returns 30+ results.
Results look like this:

```
id,          name,         latitude,         longitude
1 ,        point1,       53.3917409,        -2.1684337    
2 ,        point2,       53.4135577,        -2.1673014    
3 ,        point3,       53.3991094,        -2.2513453
```

It looks like there is something wrong with binding floats because

```
  $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM point
        WHERE latitude <= :ne_lat
          AND latitude >= :sw_lat
          AND longitude <= :ne_lon
          AND longitude >= :sw_lon
          AND status=1
    ";

    $poi = Fitter::findBySql($sql, [':ne_lat' => $ne_lat, ':sw_lat' => $sw_lat, ':ne_lon' => $ne_lon, ':sw_lon' => $sw_lon])->asArray()->all();
```

Also doesn't return any record

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

$sw_lon = 2.288761138916; `<--` this is positive in the first query while in the second it is negative (-2.288761138916).

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't an issue - I've just misspelled it when i was writing this question...

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong, using the find() method will return you this query statement.

SELECT * 
      FROM `point` 
      WHERE (atitude <= 53.42712825923) 
      AND (latitude >= 53.39008549731)
      AND (longitude <= -2.1651649475098)
      AND (longitude >= -2.288761138916)
      AND (`status`=1)

And not

SELECT * 
      FROM `point` 
      WHERE (((((latitude <= 53.42712825923) 
      AND (latitude >= 53.39008549731)) 
      AND (longitude <= -2.1651649475098)) 
      AND (longitude >= -2.288761138916)) 
      AND (`status`=1))

The difference in sql statement might be the cause.

Comment: I've tried both queries in phpmyadmin and both return me same result - there is no difference in using brackets + AND.

I've just updated question with expected results...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 'status = 1' instead of 'status' => 1 in the first query builder.